# Using wordpress login functions

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

Does anybody have any experience writing a custom Wordpress login page using the functions:

```
wp_signon()
and wp_set_auth_cookie()
```

found on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/

I can't seem to get them working.

The code looks something like this:

```
function login_wordpress($username, $password) {
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $username;
    $creds['user_password'] = $password;
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
       echo $user->get_error_message();
       die();
    } else {
         wp_set_auth_cookie( $user, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something basic?

Answer (score 9):

You need to change this line:

```
wp_set_auth_cookie( $user, 0, 0);
```

To this:

```
wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, 0, 0);
```

`$user` is a `WP_User` Object not user id.

`wp_signon` returns `WP_Error` on failure, or `WP_User` on success.

Comment: Ten years later ... now you need to use this:  wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, 1, is_ssl() );

Answer (score 4):

Was having real trouble myself... finally got it to work..!!
(after several days of experimenting and banging my head against it)

One thing to make sure is that you haven't sent any output yet 
or the session cookie won't write as it needs to be in the header. 
Also if you call wp_signon *before* the session starts, there session
info gets lost also... sheesh... strange but I had both happening 
to me. Anyhoo no more ado...

// Create new user (for example)

```
$userdata = array('user_login'->$username,'user_pass'->$password);
$user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
```

// Make sure username is up to date... I needed this as there was 
a hook to user_register being called in wp_insert_user but that
hook is called *after* the user is created, so it needed a DB
cache clear to work otherwise the wrong username was set...
So the user was auto-logged in for one page only - ridiculous.
(It was Register Plus Redux doing the hooking btw.)

```
wp_cache_delete($user_id, 'users');
wp_cache_delete($username, 'userlogins');
$userdata = get_userdata($user_id);
$username = $userdata->user_login;
```

// Make sure user session has started

```
$vsessionid = session_id();
if (empty($vsessionid)) {session_name('PHPSESSID'); session_start();}
```

// Login Current User

```
wp_clear_auth_cookie();
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $username;
$creds['user_password'] = $password;
$creds['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon($creds, false);
```

// Check it worked

```
if (is_wp_error($user)) {$error = $user->get_error_message();}
else {
    wp_set_current_user($user_id);
    // The next line *really* seemed to help!
    do_action('set_current_user');
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (is_wp_error($current_user)) {$error = $user->get_error_message();}
}

if ($error) {echo $error; print_r($userdata); print_r($current_user);}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
current_user();

function current_user()
{
    global $current_user,$user_ID;

    if(is_user_logged_in())
    {
        echo 'User Logged in '.$user_ID;
    }
    else {
        echo 'No user is logged in< br/>';
        custom_login();
    }
}

function custom_login() {
    $creds = array('user_login' => '<USERNAME>', 'user_password' =>   '<USERPASSWORD>', 'remember' => true );
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    wp_set_current_user($user->ID); 
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true, false );    
    do_action( 'wp_login', '<USERNAME>' );

    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
        echo $user->get_error_message();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I did this in a project a few years ago, so the Wordpress code was a bit different. But this code worked for me:

```
// include the wordpress files necessary to run its functions
include('../classpages/wp-config.php'); // this includes wp-settings.php, which includes wp-db.php, which makes the database connection
include(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable-functions.php');

// use wordpress's function to create the login cookies
// this creates a cookie for the username and another for the hashed password, which wordpress reauthenticates each time we call its wp_get_current_user() function
wp_setcookie($user_login, $user_pass, false, '', '', $cookieuser);
```

I didn't have to use wp_signon at all, but that may have changed.

Are you getting an error message, or what do you see when you run your code?

Comment: No error message - nothing happens.  wp_setcookie is deprecated.