# Integrating wordpress authentication with an existing user database

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have a database with a user table that has the fields:

```
id 
name 
email 
password 
status
```

My users login by giving the email and password.  I have installed a blog that has the path mysite.com/news.

What I want is that if some user registers in my site it should automatically add a row in my wordpress database.  And I want to fetch all my records of my user table and store in the wordpress user table. Also, if someone logs into in my site it should logged in when they go to the blog.

Comment: Related: [Synchronize WordPress user accounts across multiple domains and installations without using WordPress MU](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3924/synchronize-wordpress-user-accounts-across-multiple-domains-and-installations-wi)

Answer (score 5):

Why duplicate the information? You would also have to take measures to get a consistent user management between the two databases.

I suggest using the existing database as the authentication source for WordPress using this plug-in: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/external-database-authentication/

**Update:**

To allow users to be already logged in to WordPress, set the WordPress authentication cookie when they login on your website. You do this by including the minimum required WordPress code and call the *wp_setcookie()* function.

```
// include the wordpress files necessary to run its functions
include('../classpages/wp-config.php'); // this includes wp-settings.php, which includes wp-db.php, which makes the database connection
include(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable-functions.php');

// use wordpress's function to create the login cookies
// this creates a cookie for the username and another for the hashed password, which wordpress reauthenticates each time we call its wp_get_current_user() function
wp_setcookie($user_login, $user_pass, false, '', '', $cookieuser);
```

From [Using wordpress login functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734237/using-wordpress-login-functions)

Comment: its not working when i activate its giver  mysql error like some

Comment: Thanx Its Working perfect . Now I want to Know if some user login in my existing Site and he come to  blog. his session should be  same as  my existing site session .how can i do this ?

Comment: where to keep this function ? can you explain some more

Comment: You need to run it after the user is logged in to your first website. So right after you log in the user to the website, run the WordPress specific code I showed.

Comment: If you need to look up the options for wp_setcookie() you can find them here: http://72.233.56.142/Function_Reference/wp_setcookie

Comment: thnx doing succefuuly.i need some update in external-database-authentication . any more one helping link?

Comment: i want disable edit user profile and  give permissions of some users from my external db to add news also on admin panel. how to set role in this plugin and how compare this ?

Comment: disable profile is solved now just only issue of role of user . how can i sole or edit plugin ?

Comment: The plugin has an option for checking user role in your existing database "1. Do user role checks from the external database: you can set the plugin to check from a specific role field and compare to a value to allow login to wordpress."

Comment: i want login all users as subcriber but  i have some users that i want give permissions to add news buy login in  wordpress  they are my e-reporter users how can i distingish betwwn them

Comment: @ Niklas Lindblad: there is little problem the function as you tell working perfect on my local but on server it not generate cookie and this is not working on server . how can i fix this issue ?kindly reply

Comment: plz help me some thing about this probel my whole day spent in researching this error but i cant how to fix this issue. in my localhost its work perfect but on server its not work

Comment: @ Niklas Lindblad i need some help i am last 4 days at same postion the code for set cookie you tell me working perfect on local but on my server its not working . reply plz

Comment: @user1138383, this comment might be late, but check your server logs to see what error it gives it could be read/write permission issues. Also it could be php and wordpress version issues. So check and make sure your php and wordpress version are the same on both localhost and the server. Thanks