# Adding Extra Validation To WordPress User Registration

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I'm creating a members only Parent Directory for my son's high school International Baccalaureate website. This directory will contain contact information (names, street addresses, phone numbers, email addresses) of parents from each grade who have students currently enrolled in the IB program. I need to be able to authenticate a parents access to the directory against a valid student ID (which is a number).

I have a spreadsheet that contains the names of each student, their student ID, and their parent's names. There are some instances where a family has more than one student/student ID.

I'm trying to figure how I should be thinking about this, as a general approach. I have a few ideas but I need to distill them down to a more succinct inquiry.

1. One thought would be to bulk create wp subscriber accounts for all students. Their student IDs would somehow be appended to the user record. Parents would be directed to a login page, where they would login with the username of their child, password(which could be reset), and a fixed student id. If validation passes, they are redirected to the directory page.
2. Another thought would be to create user accounts on the fly that references a separate table which includes the student ID. So long as that unique student ID is part of the registration and it authenticates, anyone who has that number can register a profile.

In either scenario, once an account is created, the contact profile could either be pre-populated with the users info or updated at that time.

So my question is: Am I thinking about this in the right way? If so or if not, how can I better define this idea to get a more accurate scope? And then, ultimately, I need some direction on some possible options for getting it done in DIY way.

Sorry for the long word count. Your feedback is greatly appreciated. Below are some links that seem to be in the neighborhood of what I'm trying to do.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45900/adding-extra-authentication-field-in-login-page

[Integrating wordpress authentication with an existing user database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922546/integrating-wordpress-authentication-with-an-existing-user-database)