# Integrate website login with wordpress login

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, customization

[Using wordpress login functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734237/using-wordpress-login-functions)

As reference to above link i tried to integrate login of wordpress with my website

But it shows follwing error
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_signon()

I am using codeigniter framework... and i call it from one of model

Comment: `wp_signon()` is not a native PHP function OR a function defined in CodeIgniter. You have to create the function yourself (by manually copying it or writing it on your own).

Comment: As Repox commented. The function does not exists, the `wp_` in the function name stands for `Word Press`..

Comment: [`wp_signon()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) is a WordPress native function. .

Answer (score -1):

I need to see your code.

If you are trying to use [`wp_signon()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) without properly loading the WordPress core it isn't going to work. You need to include `wp-blog-header.php` before you try to use WordPress functions.

The information in the thread you found assumes that you are already in a WordPress environment. In your case, it sounds like you are not.

Comment: I have included follwing files... include('blog/wp-config.php');    include('blog/wp-blog-header.php');    include('blog/wp-includes/plugin.php');    include('blog/wp-includes/user.php');    include('blog/wp-includes/pluggable.php');   include('blog/wp-includes/pluggable-deprecated.php');

Comment: Now it shows following error... Fatal error: Cannot redeclare site_url()

Comment: You should only need to `include('blog/wp-blog-header.php');` The others will load. Something else is going wrong. Do you have access to any of the WordPress core functions or is the problem only with that one?

Comment: The error is because you are including files multiple times. `wp-blog-header.php` will result in the inclusion of all of those other files. Take a quick look at its source and follow the boot chain.

Comment: It still showing following error... Fatal error: Cannot redeclare site_url() (previously declared in --my-websitepath--\helpers\url_helper.php:42) in --my-websitepath--\blog\wp-includes\link-template.php on line 1903

Comment: What is "\helpers\url_helper.php"? That is not a directory or a file I have ever seen in a WordPress install. Possibly WordPress and some other software is defining the same constant?

Comment: That file does not belongs to wordpress. My website is in Php with codeigniter framework. So may be conflict in files.